# Android - How to queue multiple jobs in one background thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to run multiple time-consuming functions in background from main thread in android, 
and I'm doing it by running the following code every time user clicks a button.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someHeavyBackgroundProcessing(); // takes ~ 3sec

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                reflectProcessingChangesInUI();
            }
        });
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

The Problem is, when multiple background jobs are running at the same time in parallel, they are interfering with each other.

I want some way to have one background thread, and tasks will get queued there to be executed one by one instead of at parallel.

So there will be 2 threads in total. One main thread for the UI, and another background thread for all the heavy processing where each background job gets queued and processed one by one.

---

An example of interference-

UI has 2 buttons- INSERT and SHOW

On clicking INSERT, 10k rows gets inserted in sqlite db one by one, each time creating new instance of db and releasing it after each insert.

so when user clicks SHOW while an insert job is going on, user will only see the rows that have been inserted till that click.

Comment: use a `HandlerThread`

Comment: @pskink Can you give me an example?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps-dc8bf1540341#.2c6do0c5d, or just ask google for `HandlerThread`

Comment: @pskink I have googled HandlerThread, but haven't been able to find anything related to my context. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thnaks @pskink. This seems feasible. I'll check this and `ExecutorService` out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue

Example:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                someHeavyBackgroundProcessing(); // takes ~ 3sec

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        reflectProcessingChangesInUI();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            executor.execute(thread);
        }
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Rahul you are asking the same question the second time, are you aware of google search engine?

Comment: @pskink I'm asking @RoShan for an example of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, while I asked you for an example of `HandlerThread`.

Comment: Thanks @RoShan. I'll check this out and see if it works!